# getting warning message on xamarin studio (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamarin studio community v6.1.4 but when I write & run any program, every time I face a warning.

> C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5):
>   Warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install
>   the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your
>   application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK
>   or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved
>   from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of
>   reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly
>   targeted for the framework you intend. (MSB3644) (Conditional)

I tried update my software, and still having this problem.

[image]

Comment: Do you have .NET SDK installed?

Comment: how can i check that? i think i have installed Xamarin studio, gtk# for .net and .net framework.

Comment: See [this](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html) website. What is unclear in the message?

Comment: my pc has .net framework version 4.6.2 do i need to install 4.5 now?